# How to insert list of items Using Ado.net C#?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a store procedure which is taken 2 parameter 1st `projectId` and 2nd `Userid`

But i have to mapped the list to that particular project using single connection but i could not figure out how to insert whole list.

```
internal bool MapEmployeesToProject(int projectId, List<Users> lstUserToMap)
{
    int value = 0;
    bool check = true;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(VSTMConfigurations.ConnectionString);

    using (conn)
    {
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectId",projectId );
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectDetails", );
        // if there is a single user than i could pass userid here 
        // i am phasing a problem how to pass whole listOfUsers

        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = CreateCommand(conn, param))
        {
            cmd1.CommandText = "sp_MapProject";
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
                cmd1.Transaction = transaction;
                try
                {
                    value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery());
                    if (value > 0)
                    {
                        transaction.Commit();
                        check = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex1)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    check = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    transaction.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                check = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

the store procedure is

```
sp_MapProject
(@ProjectId int,@UserId int)
as
begin
     Insert into ProjectUsers values (@ProjectId,@UserId)
end
```

help please!!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [user define table type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in your database with `projectId` and `Userid` columns. Then you can use [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) to pass data to stored procedure.

e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412802/Sending-a-DataTable-to-a-Stored-Procedure

Thanks!